# Understanding Unity eulerAngles (how to limit rotation of a 2D object to 45 degrees?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, 2d, euler-angles

Please keep in mind I am a complete beginner.

I am trying to make a space shooter game. I have a 2D sprite facing upwards and this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 5.0f;

    private void Start()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.zero;

    }

    private void Update()

    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");



        Vector3 eulerAngles = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        //Debug.Log("transform.rotation angles x: " + eulerAngles.x + " y: " + eulerAngles.y + " z: " + eulerAngles.z); 

        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * speed * verticalInput * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

        if (horizontalInput > 0)
        {
            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -1) * horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime * 300);
        }

        else if (horizontalInput < 0)
        {
            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -1) * horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime * 300);
        }

        if (eulerAngles.z > 45)
        {
            //transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(45, Vector3.forward);
            Debug.Log("45");


        if (eulerAngles.z < -45)
        {
            //transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-45, Vector3.forward);
            Debug.Log("-45");
        }
```

For now, I want the log to say "45" when the value in Transform.rotation.z reaches 45, and "-45" when it reaches -45. My real intention (commented out in the code) is to then tell the sprite to stop rotation at 45 or -45 degrees.

When I press the left arrow until it rotates to 45, it works. But here's the problem... When I press right arrow, and the value of Transform.rotation.z becomes negative, and the log immediately says "45" as if any negative number is somehow superior to 45.

I notice that when I rotate the sprite in Unity, the values of Transform.rotation.z go on a sort of loop, until 180 then become negative until 0 and vice versa.

Could someone tell me what I'm missing? Am I overlooking other simpler, more effective ways to achieve what I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance for your help, I really appreciate it. I'm new and still struggling to grasp with many concepts.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved it! I only had to set a range in the condition between 45 and 180, and for the other direction between 315 and 180.

```
    if (eulerAngles.z > 45 && eulerAngles.z < 180)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-315, new Vector3(0, 0, 45));
        Debug.Log("45");
    }


    if (eulerAngles.z < 315 && eulerAngles.z > 180)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-315, new Vector3(0, 0, -45));
        Debug.Log("-45");
    }
```

This makes it work perfectly. When the sprite (spaceship) is going sideways, it rotates to that side but stops rotating at 45 degrees.